# Why my android app is consuming too much memory?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-glide

The situation is this:
I have an Activity which has one Toolbar, one Tablayout and one View Pager (that will contains 5 fragments)

Inside the first fragment I have a layout that **will contains one default fragment which will have a Recycler View** with two columns. Every element on this have an image downloaded from the Internet (with Glide and saving on cache) and when a user clicks on the holder (one element of the list), will change this default fragment on the 'layout container' to another one that will have a new Recycler View with images downloaded from the Internet using Glide. Similar to Instagram search page.

I thought Glide was the problem, but I comented all code and when I run the app on emulator it consumes 89 MB of RAM more o less.

**EXTRA INFORMATION**

- Every element on the RView inside any fragment is created from downloading an JSONArray using Volley, I put the request inside MySingleton queue and define the context as getContext() (should I use getActivity().ApplicationContext() instead of getContext()when the code is from fragment? )

(Inside the fragment that is inside the view pager which is inside an Activity)

```
MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(req);
```

Then it downloads the Picture URL and charge it on the view using Glide.

```
if(holder.publication.getPicture() != null ){
        Glide.with(holder.ctx).load(holder.publication.getPicture()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).centerCrop().into(holder.picture_imgView);
    }
```

- I'm not using static variables
- Moreover, I remove all animations from Recycler View elements and still being slow.
- I use the Android monitor and the 'Jump Java Heap' option to see how it is managing memory and the major number is on Byte[] (I don't understand using this tool)

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**
On my log, I always get this:

```
W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0xc8, repeatCount=1, eventTime=18009881, downTime=18009352, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }

I/Choreographer: Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: I sense the RAM usage is perfectly normal considering you are downloading images too.

Comment: Sometimes the value raises to 120 or 130 mb, but I think I finally solve it. It seems the problem was on drawables, they were too big. I will continue analizing to give a final solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I think I find the solution and I have concluded these things:

- Using drawables on .jpg format or any file larger than 150kb will use memory. In my case, I was using very big images as background and little images on recycler views but largen than 200kb. Those were killing Ram.
- It's better to use the local context of the fragment (getContext()) when calling a Volley Request and put it on the MySingleton queue.
- Holders on recyclerViews should be static inner classes because you're going to re-use them and it's a good way for saving memory.
- If you're using Glide on every Holder for download images and there is some link empty you should clean the ImageView: `Glide.clear(ImgView);`
- Creating Objects for calling SharedPreferences is not a good idea. It's better to use a global class which uses one context (of the activity that contents all fragments) and call SharedPreferences from there. Something like: `MyCallerClass.getInstance().getPrefsDataOfOuser();`

All of those are my conclusions that I got these days... now my app uses 50mb of memory downloading images with glide and 80mb or 90mb max on realtime searching...

Comment: I have similar problem except I do not use any big images as background. I guess your solution's biggest part was about using smaller images, how much does other suggestions helped?

Comment: Hi there, @Tony!
Yes, the major problem were the large images resources I were using as backgrounds and I must do some quick fixes to my answer. About the use of Contexts, this is ligated to references and leaks that they can produce. You must not use the Activity or Fragment (or any other Android's component) context as a reference for singletons, because singleton will long live through the application and activities will die somehow, that reference to the activity will cause a memory leak. This article is more detailed: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/mastering-android-context-7055c8478a22